# Custom Membership Provider and Role Manager getting data from MSSQL 2008 database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have MSSQL 2008 database, which is hosted on a server. The database have a table called Users. The table structure is

> USER_ID,
>   USER_NAME,
>   USER_PASSWORD,
>   USER_ROLE,
>   CREATED_BY,
>   CREATED_DATE,
>   MODIFIED_BY,
>   MODIFIED_DATE

I want to use this datatable with the Membership Provider and Role Manager. Is there a way of doing that without adding aditional tables to the database or using ASP.NET SQL Server Setup Wizard. If it is impossible, should I create a cookie to store UserId, UserName and UserRole? I configured the connectionString in the Web.config file, because I am using the Entity Framework.

Thank you i advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a [custom membership provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers).